# Who is who or whom in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to figure out which of the following two is correct:

1. I don't know who is whom in this chat?
2. I don't know who is who in this chat?

I tried to figure it out myself, but it quickly get's really complicated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *Who's who* sounds correct to me.

Comment: "Who is who" is a fixed phrase in English, *and* it has been borrowed into German. "Who is whom" does not even exist in either language. And of course on top of that you have "wer ist wer" in German, and not "wer ist wem" or "wer ist wen". There is nothing complicated here, and nothing to figure out. Everything really straightforward and right there in the open. (As a side note: there must be no question mark there. It's a declarative sentence, you are making a statement and not asking a question.)