# Traditional explanation for 'I don't remember whom is whom'

Tags: syntactic-analysis, whom, style-manuals

I'm looking for a traditional grammar explanation in regards to the sentence: 'I don't remember whom is whom.' Also I'll preface that I'm native speaker for whatever that's worth...

Now I understand that the most natural way to say this is, 'I do not remember who is who'. From that, because it's the accusative case, one should normally say:

'I do not remember him' -> 'I do not remember whom'

However, since 'is' is a copula or linking verb, the following [explanation by Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/it-is-i-versus-it-is-me) applies. My understanding is that it forces the same grammatical cases, so 'whom is whom' and thus:

'I do not remember whom is whom.'

In another 'who vs whom' [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211872/who-is-who-or-whom-in-a-sentence), one person suggests 'Who is who' is correct because it is a set phrase. Though I suppose I can accept that set phrases exist as a thing to torment learners (set phrase as it more means 'which person is which' or [other things apparently](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/who's%20who)), at the very least the why it isn't 'who is whom' can be explained by the Grammar Girl link earlier.

Also a side question: ignoring who vs whom, would it be more correct to say, 'I do not remember who being who', so leaving the verb in the infinitive form. As an example, 'I remeber him being another person.' Or perhaps the infinitive 'to be' is the most correct? At this point I don't trust my English enough to tell, and I might probably just analyzing this all wrong anyway...

Comment: Though ''I do not remember whom he hit" (from "Whom did he hit?") might still have one or two people advocating its correctness, ''I do not remember whom he is" (from "Whom is he?") has never been acceptable.

Comment: The thing is, while you would say "I do not remember **him**," you would not say *"I do not remember (that) **him is**...". You would say "I do not remember (that) **he is**...", so "whom" is not considered correct here. "Remember [direct object noun phrase]" and "Remember (that) [subordinate clause]" are two different structures.

Comment: Surely *who is whom* would be the hyper-correct form? If we break the sentence apart to apply the he/him test, you would get *I do not remember if **he** was the man I saw* and *I do not remember if the man I saw was **him***. So *I do not remember if **he** was **him*** and thus *I do not remember **who** was/is **whom***.

Comment: @1006a: The he-him test doesn't work, and is in fact usually misleading, after forms of "to be", due to differences between prescribed and usual usage of pronoun case in this position. This may be what you're intending to say, since you mention the concept of "hyper-correct" forms; if so, it was a bit too subtle for me. I would characterize "I do not remember who was/is whom" and "I do not remember whom was/is whom" as equally "hyper-correct" and equally wrong.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, by *hyper-correct* I meant *foolishly trying to shoehorn unnatural language into "correctness" based on random prescriptive rules*. I would use *who is who*, and call that "correct" because it's what people actually say. Sorry if I was too oblique.

Comment: @1006a: In my experience, "hyper-correct" usually refers specifically to unnatural language that is thought to conform to prescriptive rules, but actually doesn't. I couldn't tell if you were using the term this way

Comment: @sumelic That's pretty much what I meant, except that I would also include language that *does* conform to prescriptive rules, but at the expense of sense and/or conforming to modern convention (e.g. "mine employer" instead of "my employer" in a contemporary sentence). In this particular case, I have no actual idea how to fit the use to the rules; my "test" was meant to be over-the-top, not truth.

Answer (score 3):

Given that this is correct:

> I just barely remembered that  『**he was still “she”』** back then.

It follows directly that you must use subject case for both subject and predicate:

> I don’t remember 『**who is who**』.

The thing you’re remembering — 『the syntactic constituent』 — is the entire clause, and pronouns within that clause always take the case corresponding to the job they’re doing in that clause.

It is only when the thing you are remembering — the syntactic constituent — is a lone pronoun does that pronoun adopt the case of its role as the direct object of *remember*.

> I remember 『**them**』 fondly.

Comment: Makes sense. I had a feeling it because it was an clause, but wasn't to confident about how to break the sentence down or what that exactly meant for the sentence when approaching it from this perspective.

Comment: Not entirely accurate. I'll try to get an answer up soon.